# Why do I need to dereference hyper's Response before setting a body?

Tags: rust

I'm getting started with Hyper (and Rust, in general) by following [their guide](https://hyper.rs/guides/0.14/server/echo/). I noticed that before setting a body on the `Response`, I need to dereference it like this:

```rust
let mut res = Response::new(Body::empty());
*res.body_mut() = Body::from("Ok, now...");
```

Why is the dereferencing necessary here? `res` doesn't *look* like a pointer in this context, so why does `res.body_mut() = Body::from("Ok, now...")` throw the following error?

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
 --> src\main.rs:8:20
  |
8 |     res.body_mut() = Body::from("Ok, now...");
  |     -------------- ^
  |     |
  |     cannot assign to this expression
  |
help: consider dereferencing here to assign to the mutably borrowed value
  |
8 |     *res.body_mut() = Body::from("Ok, now...");
  |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the dereferencing necessary here? res doesn't look like a pointer in this context, so why does res.body_mut() = Body::from("Ok, now...") throw the following error?

It's not `res` which is a pointer, it's `res.body_mut()`:

```
pub fn body_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T
```

you need to dereference the `&mut T` in order to replace the pointee, otherwise you try to assign to `res.body_mut()` itself which... doesn't make much sense.

Rust's dereference operator has [a lower precedence than method calls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence), so the method call applies first.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the precedence rule on `*`. This explains it clearly.